# Meta tag is not updating in view source - angular

Tags: angular, angular6, meta-tags, angular-universal

I am trying to update meta tag in angular 6 and angular univarsal but it changes only in inspect element not in view page source it remains the same which is on home page.

Homepage.ts
.
.
.

```
import { SeoserviceService } from "./../../services/seoservice.service";
 constructor(private metaService: Meta, public router: Router, public _seoService: SeoserviceService) {

   }
  ngOnInit() {


      this._seoService.updateTitle('Home');
      //Updating Description tag dynamically with title
      this._seoService.updateDescription('Home Page Description');
    }

}
```

about.ts
.
.
.

```
import { SeoserviceService } from "./../../services/seoservice.service";
constructor(private metaService: Meta, public _seoService: SeoserviceService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
 this._seoService.updateTitle('About');
      //Updating Description tag dynamically with title
      this._seoService.updateDescription('About Page Description');

}
```

SeoserviceService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Injectable()
export class SeoserviceService {

  constructor(private title: Title, private meta: Meta) { }


  updateTitle(title: string) {
    this.title.setTitle(title);
  }

  updateDescription(desc: string) {
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: desc })
  }

}
```

server.ts

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Warnings which given to me when i am running server.js using npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr command, are as below
WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm5/platform-server.js
410:26-50 "export 'ɵHttpInterceptingHandler' was not found in '@angular/common/http'
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm5/platform-server.js
 @ ./server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm5/platform-server.js
852:35-51 "export 'ViewportScroller' was not found in '@angular/common'
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm5/platform-server.js
 @ ./server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm5/platform-server.js
852:63-84 "export 'ɵNullViewportScroller' was not found in '@angular/common'
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm5/platform-server.js
 @ ./server.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from 
       '@angular/common';
       import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';

       export class Component
       {
        constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object)
         {
        this.PutJquery()
         }
        PutJquery()
        {
       if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        var authData = $.cookie('data');
        }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I changed it but still meta tag is not updating.
@kamalav will you be able to  share your working code with angular universal implementation , this will be great help for me.
Thanks

Comment: pls refer this,it will be helpful for u.Because I refered that only. https://github.com/angular/universal-starter .If it is not working means,i will help u

Comment: I tried it, there starter packs properly but when i integrate my project in it just doesn't work. The meta tag is not getting updated in page source but it is updating in inspect element.

Comment: ok,whether ur contents other than index.html are rendering in view page source

Comment: my content is changing respectively as per navigation but meta tag is not changing

Comment: r u getting any error while running npm run serve:ssr.if means try to fix that error like navigator not defined,window not defined,localstorage not defined.place those code under  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId))

Comment: only error i am getting is "ERROR ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comment: ok,u are using jquery inside typescript right.Put jquery code under platformbrowser like my updated code

Comment: wherever u used jquery use this logic.just put platformbrowser check

Comment: Hi It is working now.
I have uploaded all src files and node modules and running the project on server using this command "npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr". Is this a right way ?